# HTML in unix shell scripting with sequential output

Tags: html, linux, shell, unix, awk

I have a script called "main.ksh" which returns "output.txt" file and I am sending that file via mail.(list contains 50+ records, I just give 4 records for example)

mail output I am getting is:

DATE |   FEED NAMEs                      |  FILE NAMEs                     |  JOB NAMEs                   | SCHEDULED_TIME| TIMESTAMP| SIZE(MB)| COUNT| STATUS |

Dec  17 INVEST_AI_FUNDS_FEED             amlfunds_iai_20161217.txt          gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_inv_ai          TUE-SAT      02:03   0.4248  4031    On_Time

Dec  17 INVEST_AI_SECURITIES_FEED        amltxn_iai_20161217.txt            gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_inv_ai          TUE-SAT      02:03   0.0015  9       On_Time

Dec  17 INVEST_AI_CONNECTED_PARTIES_FEED amlbene_iai_20161217.txt           gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_inv_ai          TUE-SAT      02:03   0.0001  1       No_Records

I am implementing coloring for Delayed,On_Time and No_Records field and I wrote below script which gives me bottom output(output is correct but there is no space separated).

```
awk 'BEGIN {
print "<html>" \
"<body bgcolor=\"#333\" text=\"#f3f3f3\">" \
"<pre>"
}

NR == 1 { print $0 }

NR > 1 {
if      ($NF == "Delayed")     color="red"
else if ($NF == "On_time")     color="green"
else if ($NF == "No_records")  color="yellow"
else                           color="#003abc"

$NF="<span style=\"color:" color "\">" $NF "</span>"

print $0
}

END {
print "</pre>" \
"</body>" \
"</html>"
}
' output.txt > output.html
```

output with perfect coloring:

| DATE | FEED NAMEs | FILE NAMEs | JOB NAMEs | SCHEDULED_TIME| TIMESTAMP| SIZE(MB)| COUNT| STATUS |

Dec  17 INVEST_AI_FUNDS_FEED             amlfunds_iai_20161217.txt          gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_inv_ai          On_Time

Dec  17 INVEST_AI_SECURITIES_FEED        amltxn_iai_20161217.txt            gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_inv_ai          On_Time

Dec  17 INVEST_AI_CONNECTED_PARTIES_FEED amlbene_iai_20161217.txt           gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_inv_ai          No_Records

There are 4 columns are skipped automatically. Could you please help me on this please ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: After some hours re-reading your post I realized that you want to keep the **tabular look**. And I think I know why your awk script deletes those multiple blanks between a field and the next one. This problem ocurrs when you **modify** any of the fields of the input line like, for instance, when your code changes the last field: `$NF="<span style=\"color:" color "\">" $NF "</span>"`. In the man pages of [awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) you can read: `Assigning  a value to an existing field causes the whole record to be rebuilt when $0 is referenced.`

Comment: whether print fixed-width columns into the `<pre>` tag using AWK's `sprintf()`, or `printf()`: `awk '{ printf("%-20s%15s", $1, $2) }' <<< 'abc    123'`, or build a table. Not necessarily using the `<table>` tag. You can build a table using only `<div>`s and CSS.

Comment: I don't post an answer, because I don't like the input format. A filename may contain spaces, tabs, newlines, actually anything, except `\0`, and `/`. By default, AWK splits the lines into fields by spaces. You can pass another delimiter with `-F` option. It could be `/`, for instance. But how do you know that the rest of the fields won't contain a slash? I mean that the input format is far from perfect for this task. I'd suggest XML, or JSON, or any other kind of strict format.

Answer (score 0):

When your code executes this

```
$NF="<span style=\"color:" color "\">" $NF "</span>"

print $0
```

the input line is rebuilt and therefore the multiple blanks between two consecutive fields **are replaced by just ONE only blank space**.

My solution copies the input line in a variable, deletes the last field (changing the value of the variable, not the input line), adds the modified last field and prints:

```
Dummy=$0
sub("[^ ]+$","",Dummy)   # removes last field
Dummy=Dummy "<span style=\"color:" color "\">" $NF "</span>"

print Dummy
```

Best regards

**update**: the last two code lines can be reduced in this way:

```
print Dummy "<span style=\"color:" color "\">" $NF "</span>"
```

Comment: I used your command but I am getting output with duplication, I mean there are two lines for each and every row.
Example
Nov 22 d1_psar_balance_20161122.txt  07:18  0.116  167  On_Time
Nov 22 d1_psar_balance_20161122.txt  07:18  0.116  167  On_Time
Nov 22 d2_psar_balance_20161122.txt  16:25  0         0 No_Records
Nov 22 d2_psar_balance_20161122.txt   16:25 0        0       No_Records

Comment: Hi Sir, Your code is working fine. But it is not working if the input file contents more columns (question is updated). Could you please help me on this please ?

Comment: My answer solved your initial question. If you have another question, please open a [new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209524/how-html-works-in-awk-command-in-shell-scripting) as you have done using another user. Why do you use different users?