# How HTML works in awk command in shell scripting?

Tags: html, shell, unix, awk

I have a script called "main.ksh" which returns "output.txt" file and I am sending that file via mail (list contains 50+ records, I just give 3 records for example).

mail output I am getting is: (10 cols)

```
DATE  FEED    FILE_NAME   JOB_NAME SCHEDULED TIME SIZE COUNT STATUS 
Dec 17 INVEST     iai     guxmow080 TUE-SAT 02:03 0.4248 4031 On_Time
Dec 17 SECURITIES amltxn  gdcpl3392 TUE-SAT 02:03 0.0015 9    Delayed
Dec 17 CONNECTED amlbene  gdcpl3392 TUE-SAT 02:03 0.0001 1    No_Records
```

output with perfect coloring: (6 cols only)

```
DATE  FEED    FILE_NAME   JOB_NAME SCHEDULED TIME SIZE COUNT STATUS 
Dec 17 INVEST     iai     guxmow080 On_Time(green color)
Dec 17 SECURITIES amltxn  gdcpl3392 Delayed(red color)
Dec 17 CONNECTED amlbene  gdcpl3392 No_Records(yellow color)
```

I am implementing coloring for Delayed, On_Time and No_Records field and I wrote below script which gives me bottom output.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
print "<html>" \
"<body bgcolor=\"#333\" text=\"#f3f3f3\">" \
"<pre>"
}

NR == 1 { print $0 }

NR > 1 {
if      ($NF == "Delayed")     color="red"
else if ($NF == "On_time")     color="green"
else if ($NF == "No_records")  color="yellow"
else                           color="#003abc"

Dummy=$0
sub("[^ ]+$","",Dummy)
print Dummy "<span style=\"color:" color (bold ? ";font-weight:bold" : "")(size ? ";font-size:size" : "") (italic ? ";font-style:italic" : "") "\">" $NF "</span>"

}

END {
print "</pre>" \
"</body>" \
"</html>"
}
' output.txt > output.html
```

There are 4 columns are skipped automatically.

Comment: Your script works perfectly for me (copy pasted it). Are you sure output.txt is the right format? This was checked before the edit with Dummy.

Comment: @kabanus, Hello Sir, I guess so coz I printed all 10 cols using awk as below awk '{printf("%-5s%s\t%-33s%-35s%-39s%s\t%s%-3s\t%s\t%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10)}' > output.txt

Comment: If $7-10 don't exist that will still work. Can you copy paste the first 4 lines of output.txt as they are (not using awk or anything)? The new version duplicates lines but still shows all columns for me.

Comment: Here are 4 lines

Dec 18 ENTITY Lux_Entity uxmow080 DAILY 07:01 0.0003 2 DELAYED

Dec 18 FUND Lux_Fund uxmow080 DAILY 07:01 0.0008 2 ON_Time

Dec 18 SEC Lux_Investment uxmow080 DAILY 07:01 0.0002 2 DELAYED

Dec 18 INVEST Lux_Investor uxmow080 DAILY 07:01 0.0006 2 DELAYED

Comment: Weird as heck. Try putting #!/bin/bash at the top, I'm using bash so maybe that's it though it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @user7268185: please add the `4 lines` above to your question (in a formatted block) and remove them from comments, as they are not very readable here. Thanks.

Comment: You probably have control-Ms in your input file, run dos2unix or similar to remove them then try again. Also post the actual html output.

Comment: @EdMorton, Sir, I am unable to attached the output screenshot in the que(showing less reputations)

Comment: @kabanus,@Ed Morton, Greetings, I am able to print all columns in html when I am giving all the columns with a tab separated (output.txt) but not in a sequential order. kindly check the output in my answer of this question(will remove the answer after your suggestion). Thanks a lot

Comment: sorry, I didn't make my answer in a readable format:9

Comment: Please upload your file somewhere and link in your question. It might be something you can't see/copy.

Answer (score 1):

| date |   feed_names                   |  file_names                     |  job_names                     | scheduled_time| timestamp| size| count| status |

Dec 19 ISS_BENEFICIAL_OWNERS_FEED    amlcpbo_iss_20161219.txt    gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_isz_dat  WEEK_DAYS   00:03   9.3734  34758   On_Time

Dec 19 ISS_INVESTORS_FEED    amlinvest_iss_20161219.txt  gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_isz_dat  WEEK_DAYS   00:01   0.0283  82  On_Time

Dec 19 ISS_TRANSACTIONS_FEED     amltran_iss_1_20161219.txt  gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_isz_dat  WEEK_DAYS   00:12   14.022  36532   DELAYED

Dec 19 ISS_TRANSACTIONS_FEED     amltran_iss_5_20161219.txt  gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_isz_dat  WEEK_DAYS   00:23   0.0010  3   DELAYED

Dec 19 IBS_CUSTOMER_FEED     ibscust_aml_***_20161219.txt    gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_sfp_ibc  WEEK_DAYS   (11     _out_of_11)     -NA-    ARRIVED

Dec 19 IBS_DDA_NOSTRO_ACCOUNT_FEED   ibsacct_aml_***_20161219.txt    gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_sfp_ibc  WEEK_DAYS   (44     _out_of_44)     -NA-    ARRIVED

Dec 19 GP_***_TRANSACTIONS_FEED  amltrans_***_20161219.txt   gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_sfp_glo  WEEK_DAYS   (3  _out_of_30)     -NA-    ARRIVED

But when I am trying to print in a sequential order by using below command
awk '{printf("%-5s%s\t%-33s%-35s%-39s%s\t%s%-3s\t%s\t%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10)}' output.txt, I am getting the output in a sequential format
but 4 cols are skipped. Kindly suggest!!!

| date |   feed_names                   |  file_names                     |  job_names                     | scheduled_time| timestamp| size| count| status |

Dec  19 ISS_BENEFICIAL_OWNERS_FEED       amlcpbo_iss_20161219.txt           gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_isz_dat         On_Time

Dec  19 ISS_INVESTORS_FEED               amlinvest_iss_20161219.txt         gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_isz_dat         On_Time

Dec  19 ISS_TRANSACTIONS_FEED            amltran_iss_1_20161219.txt         gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_isz_dat         DELAYED

Dec  19 ISS_TRANSACTIONS_FEED            amltran_iss_5_20161219.txt         gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_isz_dat         DELAYED

Dec  19 IBS_CUSTOMER_FEED                ibscust_aml_***_20161219.txt       gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_sfp_ibc         ARRIVED

Dec  19 IBS_DDA_NOSTRO_ACCOUNT_FEED      ibsacct_aml_***_20161219.txt       gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_sfp_ibc         ARRIVED

Dec  19 GP_***_TRANSACTIONS_FEED         amltrans_***_20161219.txt          gdcpl3392_uxmow080_ori_sfp_glo         YET_TO_RECEIVE

Comment: Move all of that into your question and use the editors `{}` button to format the input/output properly like you did for your code sample. Did you try my suggestion of running dos2unix or similar on the input file?

Comment: This question is related to [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738933/html-in-unix-shell-scripting-with-sequential-output), created by means of another user name. Do not hope your solutions to be rewarded by the OP.