# How to implement coloring through awk command and send it via mail?

Tags: html, shell, unix, awk, ksh

I am trying to convert a .txt file into .html file for coloring purpose and sending it via mail.
I am getting the proper coloring till "MQ-FEEDs:" as mentioned the below example.
But rest of the selected cases are printed twice and 2nd time it was colored(ex: FAILED FAILED(red)), could you please help me on this, thanks a lot!

Output I am getting:

Report:

```
|DATE | FEED NAMEs AS OF NOW          | AVG_TIME| ARR_TIME |SIZE(MB)|COUNT|STATUS |  
Jan  6 CHCK09_20170106.txt                20:46     21:15   0.180   1430    DELAYED
Jan  6 EGLOUT_xml_20170106.txt            15:46     15:46   0.008   247     On_Time   
Jan  9 MTS_SOD_20170106.TXT               07:05     00:06   4.005   1       No_Records    
MQ-FEEDs:    
Jan 09 03:39  MTS_TRANSACTION_FEED      MQ    1   3719238761373 SUCCESS SUCCESS    
Jan 09 03:37  HOGAN_TRANSACTION_FEED    MQ    1   3719235506904 FAILED  FAILED    
MANUAL-UPLOAD-FEEDs:                                                             MANUAL-UPLOAD-FEEDs:   
DB-POOL-FEEDs:                                                                   DB-POOL-FEEDs:    
NOTE : Feednames starting with PLUS sign(+) indicates they are in INPROGRESS Directory.   
   DELAYING-FILES-ARE                                                DELAYING-FILES-ARE
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/ksh
export PATH1="/auto/users/scripts"

awk 'BEGIN {
  print "<html>" \
    "<body bgcolor=\"#DEF3F0\" text=\"#003abc\">" \
    "<pre>"
}

NR == 0 { print $0 }
NR > 0 {
  if      ($NF == "DELAYED")     {color="red"; bold=1; size="15px"; italic=0;}
  else if ($NF == "On_Time")     {color="green"; bold=1; size="15px"; italic=0;}
  else if ($NF == "SUCCESS")     {color="green"; bold=1; size="15px"; italic=0;}
  else if ($NF == "FAILED")     {color="red"; bold=1; size="15px"; italic=0;}
  else if ($NF == "MQ-FEEDs:")     {color="magenta"; bold=1; size="15px"; italic=0;}
  else if ($NF == "MANUAL-UPLOAD-FEEDs:")     {color="magenta"; bold=1; size="15px"; italic=0;}
  else if ($NF == "DB-POOL-FEEDs:")     {color="magenta"; bold=1; size="15px"; italic=0;}
  else if ($NF == "No_Records")  {color="blueviolet"; bold=0; size="20px"; italic=1;}
  else if ($NF == "DELAYING-FILES-ARE")           {color="red"; bold=1; size="25px"; italic=0;}
  else                           {color="#003abc"; bold=0; size="25px"; italic=0;}

  Dummy=$0
  sub("[^ ]+$","",Dummy)
  print Dummy "<span style=\"color:" color (bold ? ";font-weight:bold" : "")(size ? ";font-size:size" : "") (italic ? ";font-style:italic" : "") "\">" $NF "</span>"
}

END {
  print "</pre>" \
    "</body>" \
    "</html>"
}
' output.txt > output.html

mail -s "$(echo -e "This is Subject\nContent-Type: text/html")"  xyz@email.com  <  output.html
```

Comment: [Duplicated question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209524/how-html-works-in-awk-command-in-shell-scripting/41220695#comment69651072_41220695)

Comment: @Jdamian, Hi Sir, This question is like of another question but here the requirement is little bit different.

Comment: @Jdamian, could you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need little tweaking for the output getting doubled.

```
  LASTFIELD=$NF      
  Dummy=$0
  gsub("[\t ]+$","",Dummy)
  gsub("[^ ]+$","",Dummy)
  print Dummy"<span style=\"color:" color (bold ? ";font-weight:bold" : "")(size ? ";font-size:size" : "") (italic ? ";font-style:italic" : "") "\">"LASTFIELD"</span>"
```

Comment: Hi Sir, It is working for me but it is removing the spaces(not in sequential), so I am not getting my output in specific space gap.
Can you help me on this please?

Comment: Edited my answer which will display with same spacings.